Unhandled Exception: PlatformException (Flutter inapp webview)
I am using the flutter_inappwebview package for a video player. Recently when updating my app from a older version of flutter to 3.4.3, I ran across this error on my Samsung tablet (SM P613). This only happens when using the above package.
Here is my code:
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

class VimeoVideoPlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  final String videoUrl;

  const VimeoVideoPlayer({Key? key, required this.videoUrl}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VimeoVideoPlayerState createState() => _VimeoVideoPlayerState();
}

class _VimeoVideoPlayerState extends State<VimeoVideoPlayer> {
  InAppWebViewController? _controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("URL IS: ${widget.videoUrl}");

    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      print("ANDROID");
    } else {
      print("NOT ANDROID");
    }

    // launchUrl(
    //   Uri.parse(widget.videoUrl),
    //   webViewConfiguration: WebViewConfiguration(
    //     enableJavaScript: true,
    //   ),
    //   browserConfiguration: BrowserConfiguration(
    //     showTitle: false,
    //   ),
    //   mode: LaunchMode.inAppWebView,
    // );

    // This is the video player for Vimeo.
    var iframe = """
      <html>
        <body style="background: #000000; margin: 0;">
          <iframe
              style="display: block; height: 100vh; width: 100%; border: none;"
              src="${widget.videoUrl}"
              frameborder="0"
              allow="autoplay; fullscreen"
              allowfullscreen>
          </iframe>
        </body>
      </html>
    """;

    return InAppWebView(
      initialData: InAppWebViewInitialData(data: iframe),
      onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
        _controller = controller;
      },
      initialSettings: InAppWebViewSettings(
        builtInZoomControls: false,
        displayZoomControls: false,
        useHybridComposition: true,
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false, // Ensure videos can autoplay
      ),
      onLoadStart: (controller, url) {},
      onLoadStop: (controller, url) {},
      onReceivedError: (controller, request, error) {
        print(error);
      },
    );
  }
}

Here is my pubspec.yaml
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.4.3 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  youtube_player_flutter: ^9.0.1
  open_file: ^3.3.2
  google_fonts: ^6.2.1
  flutter_html_all: ^3.0.0-beta.2
  provider: ^6.1.2
  http: ^1.2.2
  audioplayers: ^6.0.0
  path_provider: ^2.1.3
  path: ^1.9.0
  sqflite: ^2.3.3+1
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.3
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8
  email_validator: ^3.0.0
  pin_code_fields: ^8.0.1
  wakelock_plus: ^1.2.7
  device_info_plus: ^10.1.1
  image_picker: ^1.1.2
  permission_handler: ^11.3.1
  cached_network_image: ^3.3.1
  url_launcher: ^6.3.0
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.4.1
  syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer: ^26.2.5
  flutter_inappwebview: ^6.0.0
  video_player: ^2.9.1
  devicelocale: ^0.7.1
  share_plus: ^10.0.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.7.0
  font_awesome_flutter_named: ^1.1.2+1
  photo_view: ^0.15.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

Any help is really appreciated!
